# Playing sounds inside an array in a row when you tap the button in a tableview cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, avfoundation

I have an app where i display different guns in a table view. And i have a button in my tableview cell. I want to play the guns sounds when i tap those buttons. I have created an array for my audio files. And i believe i have made progress but i couldn't achieve what i want. Thank you for your help

HERE IS MY CODE

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController6: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //Array of Rifles

    var arrayOfRifles = ["AK47", "AUGA1", "FAMAS", "G36K", "K1A", "K2", "M4A1", "M4Silencer", "M16", "M60", "MicroGALIL", "QBZ95", "RPK", "ScarHeavy", "Scarlight", "SG552", "TAR21", "Tommy", "Type89", "XM8"]
    var buttonDataRifles = ["AK47", "AUGA1", "FAMAS", "G36K", "K1A", "K2", "M4A1", "M4Silencer", "M16", "M60", "MicroGALIL", "QBZ95", "RPK", "ScarHeavy", "Scarlight", "SG552", "TAR21", "Tommy", "Type89", "XM8"]
    var soundArrayRifles = ["AK47", "AUGA1", "FAMAS", "G36K", "K1A", "K2", "M4A1", "M4Silencer", "M16", "M60", "MicroGALIL", "QBZ95", "RPK", "ScarHeavy", "Scarlight", "SG552", "TAR21", "Tommy", "Type89", "XM8"]

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: NSString, type: NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer? {

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file as String, ofType: type as String)
        let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path!)

         var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?

        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        } catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
        return audioPlayer

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


//Functions for tableView

    //Cell - For Rifles

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (arrayOfRifles.count)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell6 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell6", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell6

        cell6.myImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfRifles[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")
        cell6.myButton.setTitle(buttonDataRifles[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
        return cell6

    }


    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let range: UInt32 = UInt32(soundArrayRifles.count)
        //FIND OUT WHICH SOUND HERE
        let sound = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(soundArrayRifles, type: "mp3")
        sound.play()

    }

    }
```

I get an error in this line. It doesn't let me to add 'soundArrayRifles' array here

```
let sound = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(soundArrayRifles, type: "mp3")
```

Comment: I think `setupAudioPlayerWithFile` is meant to take a string as its first argument, not an entire array

Comment: Ok do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your indexPath.row in the button tag so you have a reference to it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell6 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell6", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell6

    cell6.myImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfRifles[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")
    cell6.myButton.setTitle(buttonDataRifles[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
    cell6.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell6
}
```

Than in your button action do something like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let soundIndex = sender.tag
    //FIND OUT WHICH SOUND HERE
    let sound = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(soundArrayRifles[soundIndex], type: "mp3")
    sound.play()

}
```

It's not tested but it should do what you need it to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are no errors anymore. But when i build the app, it opens but when i tap a button it crashes. There is something wrong with this line '        let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path!)'

Comment: That means your path is not good. Consider index = 0 , your sound path should be "AK47.mp3". If that path is not valid, you should get nil as a response, and when you call NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path!) -- notice the ! - unwrap something that's nil it crashes.

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't quite understand what you mean

Comment: He means that your mp3 files could be in a different place to where you are trying to access them.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell6 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell6", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell6

    cell6.myImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfRifles[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")
    cell6.myButton.setTitle(buttonDataRifles[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
    cell6.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell6.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController6.buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell6
    }

    func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

            let sound = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(soundArrayRifles[sender.tag], type: "mp3")
            sound.play()

     }
```

Comment: The app crashes when i tap a button :(

Comment: Make sure the button in your cell isn't linked to any `IBAction`

Comment: I think you add the button directly in ViewController6. You should add custom class for custom row. Than you add to button your custom class.

Comment: Button outlet is in ViewControllerTableViewCell6. And Matt '    func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) ' This is the action that i have linked to my button. Are you saying i should remove it?

Comment: Ok i have deleted my button and created a new one. Then I linked IBOutlets and Actions. Now when i tap a button it doesn't crash. But there is a problem with this line now '            let sound = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(soundArrayRifles[sender.tag], type: "mp3")' It says that i have to type 'file:' before my array. But if i do it when i tap the button i dont hear any sound. How can i add my array to this line without any errors

Comment: You shouldn't add @IBAction to your button.